# Querying manytomany field using a list of objects in django returning multiple rows with same id

Tags: django, models

Say that I have a manytomany field, and say that I have x amount of elements.

```
class Distinct_Alert(models.Model):
    alert_type = models.ForeignKey(Alert_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(to='Entity', through='Entity_To_Alert_Map')
    objects = Utility_Manager()

class Entity(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    entity_type = models.ForeignKey(Entity_Type_Label)
    related_entities = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    identical_entities = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    objects = Entity_Manager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('label', 'entity_type')
```

I am currently doing something

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(alert_type=alert_type, entities__in=[entity[0] for entity in entities]).all()
```

but for some reasons, this query returns 2 distinct alerts with the same id, any idea why? If I add distinct() to it that solves the issue, but I'm trying to use get since the table should technically only have one entry matching that query.

I was initially doing this:

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.get_or_none(alert_type=alert_type, entities__in=[entity1, entity2....])
```

but then this bounced with an error, get_or_none is defined like so

```
class Utility_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_or_none(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.get(**kwargs)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

but this won't work since I have 2 elements that are being returned, it would be an odd case if the elements were different and matching on the same query, but the rows that are returned are literally the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When queries span multiple rows, duplicates should be expected.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

> By default, a `QuerySet` will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice,
>   this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as
>   `Blog.objects.all()` don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result
>   rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to
>   get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d
>   use `distinct()`

So like you've done, using `distinct` is the standard way for eliminating dups.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into 
def prefetch_related(self, *lookups):
 """
 Returns a new QuerySet instance that will prefetch the specified
 Many-To-One and Many-To-Many related objects when the QuerySet is
 evaluated.

When prefetch_related() is called more than once, the list of lookups to
 prefetch is appended to. If prefetch_related(None) is called, the list
 is cleared.
or 
def select_related(self, *fields):
 """
 Returns a new QuerySet instance that will select related objects.

If fields are specified, they must be ForeignKey fields and only those
 related objects are included in the selection.

I have used them in my select queries in views.py and works greats with manytomany and foreign keys.